# Make / link to the different directory VHost, PHP MVC

Tags: php, apache, directory-structure, vhosts

Im trying to create my own MVC. My folder structure is following:

```
 localhost (root, htdocs)
   - Project_1
     - images
       - test.jpg
     - App
       - Controllers
       - Models
       - Views
     - Classes
```

Now if i create an index file under views folder and add this:

```
    <img src="/images/test.jpg" />
```

this does not load test.jpg because `/` points to `localhost (root/htdocs)` folder and does not point to `Project_1`

My question is what do i need to do to make `/` point to `Project_1` directory instead of root, i know it has to do something with VHosts but unfortunately i do not know any tutorial that would explain the problem.

Any ideas/suggestions or links to tutorials will be appreciated. Thank you

**NOTE**:
I do not want to do the following:

```
  define('ROOT', '/localhost/Project_1/');
```

and then use it like

```
  <img src="<?=ROOT?>images/test.jpg" />
```

this is what im trying to avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are looking to do is change the base path of images then you might be able to get away with using the `<base>` HTML element.

> [Taken from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Element/base) -
>   The HTML  element specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document.

As for the PHP side of things, **the option you categorically dismissed would probably be the best way** - defining a constant pointing to the correct path -

```
define('ROOT', '/localhost/Project_1/');
```

If you want to get into the settings of your virtual host, then you'll be able to set your document root directly from the virtual host's definition. Here is a simple example -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost/Project_1/
    ServerName Project_1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Within this virtual host, your `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will now be `/var/www/localhost/Project_1/`.

Comment: Excellent this is what i needed, now will i be able to define a different VirtualHost root path for different project? say Project_2

Comment: @GGi - yep. Each virtual host definition will have it's own `DocumentRoot` and `ServerName` - so you can set them to whatever you want!